# Keras-PlaidML on CPU looks faster than Keras-TensorFlow on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plaidml

I was trying to run my Keras Sequential Model on AMD GPU on my macOS, and meanwhile noticed a strange behaviour.

When I'm training my model on CPU using Keras through PlaidML backend (the Keras version supported is 2.2.4)

```
import plaidml.keras
plaidml.keras.install_backend()
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"
os.environ["PLAIDML_DEVICE_IDS"] = "llvm_cpu.0"
```

it goes as follows:
[image: PlaidML training]

But when I'm running my code without the code block above and using TensorFlow version 2.15.0, it runs this way:
[image: TensorFlow training]

Therefore, it looks like tensorflow runs much slower even though it's a backend and it shouldn't be that way. The only thing I noticed is that when running the model using PlaidML backend it utilises more CPU power (e.g., 30-40% instead of 20-30%). The model code is exactly the same.

What can be the reason of such difference in performance?